# Get content from jquery CLEditor

Tags: jquery

How can I get content data what I am write in [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) using jquery keyup?

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it make more sense to use CLEditor's `.change` event? From the [documentation](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/docs/GettingStarted.html):

> **change** - This event is triggered whenever the contents of the editor
>   have changed. Since change detection
>   is done using the keyup and mouseup
>   events, this event occurs frequently
>   as the user types.

Comment: Yes... but how to get the content data in the change event?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 1.3.0 of the cleditor,
the following code is unofficial,
I might be bad code, because I'm oop noob AND for many other reasons, 
but until the next release it does the trick for me :
here is what I did :

In file jquery.cleditor.js :

add a trickyMethod option :
line 100 :

replace this

```
imagesPath: function() { return imagesPath(); },
```

by this :

```
imagesPath: function() { return imagesPath(); },
trickyMethod: function(){}
```

Make the trickyMethod be called on keyup event :
line :878

replace this :

```
$doc.click(hidePopups)
  .bind("keyup mouseup", function() {
    refreshButtons(editor);
  });
```

by this :

```
$doc.click(hidePopups)
  .bind("keyup mouseup", function() {
    refreshButtons(editor);
    editor.options.trickyMethod(editor);
  });
```

Now you can go in your application code and invoke the cleditor with the trickyMethod option :

```
    $("#input").cleditor({
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        trickyMethod: function(){ alert("sdf"); }
    });
```